# Is there any way to tell sed or grep that any of search patterns can occur first and we need to pick from there till next search pattern?

Tags: sed, grep

```
cat my_file  
>a1  
AAAT  
>a2  
TTAA  
>a3  
TGCA  
>a4  
TGAC  
>a5  
ATAA
```

then

```
sed '/a4/,/a2/p' my_file
```

should print out lines between patterns

```
>a2  
TTAA  
>a3  
TGCA  
>a4
```

both patterns inclusive, but currently it prints from search term a4 to the end of file

Comment: But it does not work and instead gives the unwanted output ...

Comment: I tried to format for as best I could... @ramani, could you clarify if `>a2  
TTAA` are present in two lines or single? and whether `>` is part of input or not?

Comment: @Yunnosch any other better alternative with grep ? actually my search patterns come from output of a previous script

Comment: @Sundeep At first I had the impression that the ">" only came in (visibly) due to your edit. But you might be right, OP might actually want them... indicated by not usiong them as consistent markdown.

Comment: OP, please show your current undesired output and baed on it epxlain more about what you want to achieve (differently).

Comment: @Sundeep yess >a2 TTAA are present in two different lines and my search term is just a2

Comment: So you confirm the way Sundeep edited your question?

Comment: @Yunnosch my current output is everything after 'a4' till the end of file ..actually original file is big, i have shown just part of it

Comment: Your address range is "a4" -> "a2". Your sample input seems to need "a2" -> "a4", i.e. swapped. I.e. `sed '/a4/,/a2/p' my_file` -> `sed '/a2/,/a4/p' my_file`. Does that already fix your problem?

Comment: Please edit your undesired output (and explanation) into your question, instead of "hiding" this useful information in a comment.

Comment: actually my search patterns will be generated as part of a different script, so they may be a2 -> a4 then its doing job correctly, if it is a4 -> a2 then I want the desired output as shown

Comment: If your file is big, please study the concept of making a [mcve].

Comment: So your problem is that your serach pattern gets generated potentially wrongly?

Comment: The "TGAC" is not actually "between" your search patterns, but is in desired output. Could your rephrase to avoid what seems to be a conflict between description and desired output?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is `sed -nE '/a2|a4/,/a2|a4/p' my_file`... which can be shortened to `sed -nE '/a2|a4/,//p' my_file`

Comment: Sundeep thank you so much, yes exact this is what I was looking for. Can you please tell me y E is used?

Comment: the -E option enables extended regular expressions... otherwise, you'd need to use `sed -n '/a2\|a4/,/a2\|a4/p'`

Answer (score 0):

`p` prints the current pattern space and is a command which accept address ranges.

From the Manual:

```
$ man sed | grep -A5 Addresses
Addresses
   Sed commands can be given with no addresses, in which case the command will be executed for all input lines; with one address, in  which  case  the  command
   will  only be executed for input lines which match that address; or with two addresses, in which case the command will be executed for all input lines which
   match the inclusive range of lines starting from the first address and continuing to the second address.  Three things to note  about  address  ranges:  the
   syntax is addr1,addr2 (i.e., the addresses are separated by a comma); the line which addr1 matched will always be accepted, even if addr2 selects an earlier
   line; and if addr2 is a regexp, it will not be tested against the line that addr1 matched.
```

Try this:

```
sed -n '/a2/,/a4/p' my_file
```